# IntelliJ IDEA 14 can't drag files to other packages

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Until today, in the Project view of IntelliJ IDEA 14, I could drag files from one package to another. Now I cannot.

I've confirmed that I can drag and drop outside of IntelliJ and can re-order tabs in IntelliJ, so it's not a hardware issue. Is there a setting that governs this?

Right now my workaround is F6 (Refactor -> Move) and manually specifying the destination.

Comment: What do you see when you try to drag these files across?  Do you get any kind of message?   Does this behavior persist between restarts?

Comment: I've had that as well, it was gone after I restarted IDEA. I think it's a bug.

Comment: @Makoto the file just doesn't drag, it stays where it was. I'll try restarting.

Comment: This happens to me using IntelliJ 15 too, but only periodically. It's like the click event doesn't register because there's no drag overlay for me.

Comment: Problem persists in IDEA 16

Comment: I have the same problem on IDEA 14. Restart works!

Comment: Same problem, but the root cause was that I had created a package with an invalid character. In my case, '-'.

Answer (score -1):

Hold down the alt key while performing the drag.